# creating matrix from data-set

Tags: matlab, matrix, dataset

I have a network with edges and points. The `FID` shows the ID number of each edge that is created by `Start_Point` and `End_Point`. For example edge `3` is between the two points of `2` and `3` in the network.

```
FID     Start_Point End_Point
1       1           2
2       1           4
3       2           3
4       2           4
```

I want to create a *4*-by-*4* matrix of these points. if there is an edge between 2 points the value is `1` else is `inf`:

```
[inf, 1,   inf, 1;
 1,   inf, 1,   1;
 inf, 1,   inf, inf;
 1,   1,   inf, inf]
```

How can I create such a matrix in MATLAB?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Make your output have the correct dimensions for you *5*-by-*3* input. Explain why a point in your matrix would be `inf` and why it would be `1`. What format (data type) is your input in?  Please *EDIT* your question to add these details

Comment: It is still not clear. Explain the dimensions of your output matrix, how did you get to the `(inf 1 inf inf inf ... 1)`? What are the round brackets supposed to mean??

Comment: there are 127 edges (FID) between the network of points. If there is a edge between two points, it means there is a rout ! so, the value of that edge will be 1 and if there is not a rout between two points, then there is not an edge between them. so, the value of edge will be inf.

Comment: there is 101 points in the network.. so the dimension of matrix will be 101X101. the arrays of matrix would be 1 or inf. Is it more clear?

Comment: Not much more clear I'm afraid, make an example much smaller network with an output of say *4*-by-*4* and show the full input data and output matrix. Also format your output matrix as a proper matlab matrix (i.e. drop the `()`)

Comment: Thanks for your response and editing.. hope i could explain my question well!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to a sparse matrix and then use full command to obtain adjacency matrix.

```
edges= [1 2;
    3 4;
    3 1
    2 3];
n=size(edges,1);
% create sparse matrix with given edges and their reverse direction
A = sparse([edges(:,1); edges(:,2)],[edges(:,2); edges(:,1)],[ones(n,1); ones(n,1)]);
% create adjacency matrix
B=full(A);
% set zeros to inf
B(B==0)=inf;
```

and this is the result :

```
A =

   (2,1)        1
   (3,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
   (3,2)        1
   (1,3)        1
   (2,3)        1
   (4,3)        1
   (3,4)        1

>> B

B =

   Inf     1     1   Inf
     1   Inf     1   Inf
     1     1   Inf     1
   Inf   Inf     1   Inf
```

**Edit :** 
the sparse command create a sparse matrix with addressing values of its elements. One prototype for this command is as follow :

```
A=sparse(rows,cols,values);
```

for example `A=sparse([1;2],[1,3],[10,5])` is a matrix which `A(1,1)=10` and `A(2,3)=5` and other elements are zero:

```
A=sparse([1;2],[1,3],[10,5]);
>> full(A)

ans =

    10     0     0
     0     0     5
```

In your case you have to add two directions to sparse matrix (symmetric) and all values are one. So you need to construct sparse matrix as :

```
 A = sparse([edges(:,1); edges(:,2)],[edges(:,2); edges(:,1)],[ones(n,1); ones(n,1)]);
```

**full** command convert a sparse matrix to a dense one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. please explain about line `A = sparse([edges(:,1); edges(:,2)],[edges(:,2); edges(:,1)],[ones(n,1); ones(n,1)]);` what is `[ones(n,1); ones(n,1)])` ?

Comment: @Shokouh Dareshiri, I edited the answer and I explained that.

Comment: Merc.. Thank you so much.. It was so helpful :-)

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to create an adjacency matrix from an adjacency list of edges? The number of your edges (i.e. your `FID` column) is irrelevant so I'm assuming your input data is of the form

```
edges = [1   2
         1   4
         2   3
         2   4]
```

Now the first column of edges is the rows of your adjacency matrix and the second is the columns (or vice versa, it doesn't matter since your matrix is symmetrical)

The simplest solution is to use linear index which you would get via the `sub2ind` function:

```
adj = inf(size(edges,2));
idx = sub2ind(size(adj),edges(:,1), edges(:,2))
adj(idx) = 1;
```

I suspect your `edges` matrix will already be symmetrical but if it's not then just use

```
edges_sym = [edges; fliplr(edges)]
```

instead of `edges`

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `accumarray`:

```
edges1 = accumarray([startpoint endpoint]),1);
edges2 = edges1.'; % transpose your matrix, to obtain both edges
edges = edges1+edges2;
edges(edges==0)=inf;
```

[`accumarray`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) gathers all points with common indices, pastes the value `1` on those indices. `edges1` is the transpose of `edges2`, thus transpose, then add the two together. Find all indices on which the matrix is `0`, then fill those values with `inf`.

Alternative:

```
edges= [1 2;
    3 4;
    3 1
    2 3];
matrix = accumarray([edges;fliplr(edges)],1,[],[],inf);
```

[`fliplr`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) flips your matrix left to right, to get all the desired combinations of indices. Then use `accumarray` to set a `1` on all locations specified by `edges` and put `inf` at the other locations.

If you are sure your matrix is symmetric, don't use `fliplr`, if you sure your matrix is non-symmetric, use `fliplr` and if you are not sure use this:

```
matrix = accumarray([edges;fliplr(edges)],1,[],@mean,inf);
```

where the `@mean` makes sure to set double entries to 1 anyway. For weighted edges do the following, where `weights` is an `Nx1` array containing the weights and `N` is the number of edges.

```
matrix = accumarray([edges;fliplr(edges)],weights,[],@mean,inf);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: No problem. The answer by Ali Mirzaei is probably the fastest of these three solutions for your problem, though I'd like to mention the versatility of `accumarray` for utilisation of other functions than `sparse`'s built-in `sum` functionality, if you ever need it ;). This is not an intent to steal the accept, that belongs on Ali's fast solution!

Comment: if i want to weigh edges instead of 1 then what should i do?

Comment: when i use `accumarray` , it give me error : `Undefined function 'accumarray' for input arguments of type 'dataset'`.

Comment: then you are missing the toolbox it's part of. You can use `sparse` with the same `weight` array